# Devise Internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have setup Devise for my application and have created an fr.yml file in my locales folder in order to get error messages translated.

Here is my fr.yml file at the moment.

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      client:
        password: "Mot de passe"
        email: "Email"
        password_confirmation: "Confirmation du mot de passe"
        remember_me: "Se souvenir de moi"
        log_in: "Connection"
    errors:
      models:
        client:
          attributes:
            password_confirmation:
              confirmation: "Confirmation du mot de passe"
```

(It is pretty sketchy at the moment but I will develop it later on. )

Though a fun thing is happening: when I try to create a new user of the `client` model and let's say I forget to input the password confirmation, Devise returns the following error :

***"Confirmation du mot de passe Confirmation du mot de passe"***

It seems the error message is duplicated.

I have removed all French translations for 'password_confirmation' in my `fr.yml` file and got the following error :

***"Password confirmation translation missing: fr.activerecord.errors.models.client.attributes.password_confirmation.confirmation"***

Not sure what I can do to get the fr.yml right

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know exactly why this is happening but you aren't following `Devise` localization standards.

Please check devise fr.yml from `Devise-i18n` project here : https://github.com/tigrish/devise-i18n/blob/master/rails/locales/fr.yml - you don't have to install the gem -.

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, actually your bit of code doesnt work. It seems all the translations need to be within quotation marks. But the Devise github has it all : https://gist.github.com/qsypoq/4cf3b858ff8242ffb013 (but as a separate file devise.fr.yml, no big deal though) I will first finish to document my fr.yml and see if it changes anything..

Comment: No, translations needn't to be within quotation marks.